# Sort the DataFrames columns which are dynamically generated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is similar to this

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['xyz','abc','dfg'],
               'age':[15,34,22],
               'sex':['s1','s2','s3'],
               'w-1(6)':[96,66,74],
               'w-2(5)':[55,86,99],
               'w-3(4)':[11,66,44]})
```

Note that in my original DataFrame the week numbers are generated dynamically (i.e) The columns
w-1(6),w-2(5) and w-3(4) are generated dynamically and change every week. I want to sort all the three columns of the week based on **descending** order of the values.
But the names of the columns cannot be used as they change every week.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Edit : The numbers might not always present for all the three weeks, in the sense that if W-1 has no data, i wont have that column in the dataset at all. So that would mean only two week columns and not three.

Comment: Do they respect a pattern at least in the names, like here the three columns start with `w-`? also you can see there is a number parenthesis another number?

Comment: So the pattern is something like this, "W-2(Wk5)" ,"W-1(Wk6)" and "W(Wk7)".Please note these columns might not be present if there is no data for that week and hence we cannot use column indices in the normal way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the column indices.

```
d1.sort_values(by=[d1.columns[3], d1.columns[4], d1.columns[5]] , ascending=False)
```

Comment: i forgot to mention, the values might not always present for all the three weeks And when it isn't for any week, ill get an error if i use this method right?

Comment: In that case you may find it helpful to use some conditional if statements and `df.shape[1]` to get the number of columns.